# Change from Laravel LocalHost Server to APP_URL .test

Tags: laravel

So I use the command `PHP artisan serve` to run a server and I can view my Laravel site at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ but I want to run my website at the
APP_URL= 'http://projectName.test' how can I do this? I see a lot of videos online where it just spins up that way automatically.

MySQL
Win11
XAMP

Comment: the `serve` command can take options

Comment: Thank you man that helps. I am going to look into it now.

Comment: @lagbox I haven't had any luck with this. Can you give me a tip?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a virtual host to run the project on the custom URL in localhost.

[this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart) is an example of defining a virtual host.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`php artisan serve --host=projectName.test --port=80`

Also this is `serve` manual:

```
Description:
  Serve the application on the PHP development server

Usage:
  serve [options]

Options:
      --host[=HOST]     The host address to serve the application on [default: "127.0.0.1"]
      --port[=PORT]     The port to serve the application on
      --tries[=TRIES]   The max number of ports to attempt to serve from [default: 10]
      --no-reload       Do not reload the development server on .env file changes
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi  Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

Answer (score 0):

change host file parameter like:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1           projectName.test
```

change directory to root project and run:

```
php artisan serve --host=projectName.test --port=80
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at [Laragon](https://laragon.org/). I think Laragon is a better choice than XAMPP. And in your case, using Laragon don't require you to run `php artisan serve` to run the app. Just turn on the Laragon, and your app will be able to be accessed from `http://your-app.test` (suffix can be changed). No additional configuration or changes needed.